# Broadcast receiver is not receiving

Tags: android, broadcast

I have a broadcast receiver that is not ever getting triggered. The Intentservice is in a separate class from the main activity and is starting the intent service broadcast just fine, or so it seems, but the broadcast receiver in the main activity is never receiving the activity. I have some logcats in the method of the broadcast receiver and they are never getting displayed which leads me to believe that the program is never getting to that point. I don't know if its something to do with how I have it setup, whether that be in the manifest or what. I'm just not sure why the program is never getting to the broadcastreceiver class.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
    static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.example.assignment6.CALL";
    public static final String CALL_NUMBER = "CALL_NUMBER";
    private Button callButton;
    private Button cancelButton;
    private EditText numberText;
    private long number;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    public class CallReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private int number;
        private static final String TAG = "SERVICE";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            Log.i(TAG, "Just before intent create");
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent1.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
            context.startActivity(intent1);
            Log.i(TAG, "After startActivity");
        }
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    public void setMinute(int minute) {
        this.minute = minute;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        callButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scheduleButton);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        numberText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberText);
        callButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        number = Long.parseLong(numberText.getText().toString());
        showTimePickerDialog(arg0);
        showDatePickerDialog(arg0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra("year", year);
        intent.putExtra("month", month);
        intent.putExtra("day", day);
        intent.putExtra("hour", hour);
        intent.putExtra("minute", minute);
        intent.putExtra("number", number);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MainActivity.ACTION_RESP);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        year = newFragment.getYear();
        month = newFragment.getMonth();
        day = newFragment.getDay();
    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        hour = newFragment.getHour();
        minute = newFragment.getMinute();
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
}
```

**IntentService:**

```
public class CallIntentService extends IntentService {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int minute;
    private int hour;
    private int number;
    private static final String TAG = "SERVICE";
    public CallIntentService() {
        super("PhoneCall");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
                year = intent.getIntExtra("year", year);
                month = intent.getIntExtra("month", month);
                day = intent.getIntExtra("day", day);
                minute = intent.getIntExtra("minute", minute);
                hour = intent.getIntExtra("hour", hour);
                number = intent.getIntExtra("number", number);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                Log.i(TAG, "just before if statement");
                Log.i(TAG, currentCal.YEAR + "");
                Log.i(TAG, cal.YEAR + "");
                // Only checking year
                if(currentCal.YEAR == cal.YEAR){
                    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("your.intent");
                    broadcastIntent.setAction(MainActivity.ACTION_RESP);
                    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.CALL_NUMBER, number);
                    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                    Log.i(TAG, "In if statement");
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.assignment6"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name=".CallIntentService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="CallReceive"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="CALL_NUMBER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.example.assignment6.CALL";
```

to

```
static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.example.CallIntentService";
```

Comment: Still seems to not work. Not sure what im doing wrong for it to not trigger then receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change that:

```
<receiver
        android:name="CallRecieve"
        android:enabled="true" >
```

into (mind the dot in the name):

```
<receiver
        android:name=".CallRecieve"
        android:enabled="true" >
```

Comment: Ya still not getting into the receiver method. Dont know why its not hitting that method.